# Удаление пустых строк из списка

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

Написал небольшую программу. Есть textbox, в который я записываю строчки, будь то ФИО или обычные товары. Далее, по нажатию кнопки программа сортирует список по алфавиту. Однако мне нужно еще предостеречься тех случаев, когда пользователь вводит пустые строки, по типу:

- enter
- enter
- enter
- Курчатов Игорь Васильевич
- enter
- enter
- Андрей Николаевич Туполев
- enter
- Юлий Борисович Харитон

(моя программа не игнорирует/удаляет пустые строки, она их попросту закидывает наверх списка)

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void cmSort(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbSort.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка, введите список");
                tbSort.Text = "";
            }
            else
            { 
            List<string> a = new List<string>(); 
            string[] txt = tbSort.Text.Split('\n');
                for (int i = 0; i < txt.Count(); i++)
                {                 
                    try 
                    {
                        if ((txt[i] != " ") && (txt[i] != "\n"))
                        a.Add(Convert.ToString(txt[i]));
                    }
                    catch { }         
                }
                a.Sort();
                tbSort.Text = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < a.Count(); i++)
                    tbSort.Text += a[i] + "\n"; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: `.Split('\n', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: Подсказка: `a.Count()` лучше используйте свойство `a.Count`, а для массива - `txt.Length`. Еще вот это `Convert.ToString(txt[i])` можно просто `txt[i]`, потому что вы строку в строку преобразуете. Зачем? Будьте внимательны.

Comment: Еще вот это `tbSort.Text += a[i] + "\n"` можно так `tbSort.AppendText(a[i] + "\n")`, второй вариант намного быстрее первого, особенно на больших текстах. И гаконец, вместл `"\n"` используйте `Environment.NewLine`